# Can i snap Highstock navigator extremes to existing points?

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking for a way to snap the users min and max extremes to existing points when they use the navigator slider. Is this something i can accomplish with existing options or has anyone else accomplished this? The ultimate goal here would be if i set two points in a series, for example (1365444905, 1) and (1365444919, 10) when the user slides the bar i should only ever get back 1365444905 or 1365444919.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do this using existing options. I think that it requires some modification in navigator `mouseMoveHandler` method. You can find it here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/5b1f3b0bc492252bbe0e283ec698480dbc179ba5/js/parts/Scroller.js#L651

Here's the part of function you should take a look at:

```
// drag left handle
if (scroller.grabbedLeft) {
    hasDragged = true;
    scroller.render(0, 0, chartX - navigatorLeft, scroller.otherHandlePos);

// drag right handle
} else if (scroller.grabbedRight) {
    hasDragged = true;
    scroller.render(0, 0, scroller.otherHandlePos, chartX - navigatorLeft);

// drag scrollbar or open area in navigator
} else if (scroller.grabbedCenter) {

    hasDragged = true;
    if (chartX < dragOffset) { // outside left
        chartX = dragOffset;
    } else if (chartX > navigatorWidth + dragOffset - range) { // outside right
        chartX = navigatorWidth + dragOffset - range;
    }

    scroller.render(0, 0, chartX - dragOffset, chartX - dragOffset + range);
}
```